Get data from Firebase Database Structure and Show it in multiple elements
I try to get all the datas from a specific section on my Firebase Database and show the information into a list-bar.
Here is the code:
import React from 'react'
import { RiDeleteBin6Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { FaExchangeAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import { ref, child, get } from 'firebase/database'
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export const CardDateList = ( ) => {

    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser.reloadUserInfo.localId;

    if (user !== null) {

        get(child(dbRef, `locations/identify/${user}`)).then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
  
        let LocationName = (snapshot.val().name);

        get(child(dbRef, `locations/public/${LocationName}/availabledates/`)).then((snapshot) => {

          var DataDateList =[];
          
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
              DataDateList.push(childSnapshot.val());
            });
          
          console.log(DataDateList);

  return (
    <div className='container_date_element'>
        <label key={DataDateList.date}>
            <div className='container_date_list_element' id={DataDateList.date}>
                <form className='form_date_list_element'>
                    <div className='list_element'>
                        <label>{DataDateList.date}</label>
                        <br></br>
                        <input></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='list_element'>
                        <label>{DataDateList.genre}</label>
                        <br></br>
                        <input></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='list_date_button'>
                          <button><FaExchangeAlt/></button>
                          <button><RiDeleteBin6Line/></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
  );
})


} else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }

  
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});


  };
};

My structure is looks like this on Firebase:

How can I get the data from the 4 different dates (availabledates) and pass the list to the list-bar?
the console.log is showing this:


The way you read availabledates and then loop over the results looks fine at first glance.  Does the console.log(DataDateList); not show the correct data? Or is something else going wrong?

Thanks for your answer @FrankvanPuffelen. The console.log shows all 4 elements but i'm not able to create 4 list-bars with the informations. How can i fetch the data  for each of this data (2024-05-02T01:12, 2024-05-13T01:12, and so on)?

Since the console.log shows the correct information, you're already fetching the right information and processing it correctly. The problem seems to be in getting that information to show in the UI. Have you heard of useState?

@FrankvanPuffelen thanks again :)
I heard about useState. I'm new to react and i think i have to watch a tutorial and read about useState.
Could you tell me how it would be on my code? Just to understand.

The link I provided has all the information needed to get started. If you I recommend following that documentation, first seeing how it works there, and only then trying to apply it to your situation. If you run into trouble in that last step, post a new question that shows what you tried and where you got stuck.

@FrankvanPuffelen thank you so much. I will follow the documentation :)

Since the console.log shows the correct information, you're already fetching the right information and processing it correctly. The problem seems to be in getting that information to show in the UI.
When you load data dynamically, you need tell React that it needs to refresh the UI. The common way to do that is to update the state of the component, which you can do with useState.
